# Is it possible to override non-virtual slots in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I would like to run some of my code when the `resizeColumnsToContents` slot gets called. However the `resizeColumnToContents` slot is not virtual. Is there any other way to achieve this?

If the slot was virtual this is what I would like to do:

```
class DerivedTableView : public QTableView
{
public:
  void resizeColumnsToContents()
  {
    printf("The user wants to resize the columns\n");
    QTableView::resizeColumnsToContents();
  }
};
```

Comment: You cannot override non virtual function. Who calls `resizeColumnsToContents` slot? It's connected to a signal, right? To which one? You can implement your own slot (function) and connect the same signal to that very slot instead.

Comment: Ah, great idea. I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I found that `QHeaderView::sectionHandleDoubleClicked` signal calls this slot. Fortunately it is accessible and I can use to connect to my slot. Awesome, thank you.

Comment: Well you can actually override a non-virtual function as long as you don't call it on a motherclass type pointer, but in your case this is not relevant.